# Show that $ \mathbf u^2 \mathbf v^2 = (\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v)^2 - (\mathbf u \wedge \mathbf v)^2 $

Tags: geometric-algebras

where $ \mathbf u $ and $ \mathbf v $ are vectors. From Linear and Geometric Algebra by Alan Macdonald.

Comment: I think there should be + instead of - in RHS

Comment: The print definitely has a '-'. How would you prove it if it were a '+'?

Comment: What is a multivector?If the $\wedge$ is the cross product of vectors, then I would say that $u$, $v$ are in $\mathbb R^3$. Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure $u$ and $v$ are multivectors instead of just vectors?  Chris's answer doesn't seem to work if they're actually multivectors.

Comment: @Murphid - I edited the question. It was a false assumption on my part.

Comment: Your sign is obviously wrong. To see this, just take any non-zero $\mathbf u, \mathbf v$ with $\mathbf{u.v} = 0$.

Comment: @TonyK Taking $ u = e_1 , v = e_2 $ I get L.H.S = 1, R.H.S $ = 0 - (e_1\wedge e_2)^2 = 1 $. Where is the problem?

Comment: @user99712: If $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are ordinary vectors, then $\mathbf{(u \wedge v)}^2$ is positive, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I see. $\mathbf u \wedge \mathbf v$ is to be interpreted as a multivector. But you edited your question to remove all references to multivectors, so I didn't pick up on that...

Comment: In the context of this being an expression in geometric algebra (a clifford algebra over the real numbers), it should be clear that this is a wedge product (and not a cross product just confusingly denoted with wedge). Still, a couple people have had this issue.  What can we do (with tags, or something else) to make the proper context clearer?

Comment: @Muphrid: Tag it as "not for the over-50's". I never learnt this stuff at university...

Comment: Yeah, while Hestenes was working on this stuff in the 70s, I don't think it's really taken off except in the last 20 years.  And by taken off, I mean "worked on by more than a few enthusiasts". But I think anyone with enough background in vector algebra can come to appreciate the advantages of geometric algebra over index notation and differential forms.

Comment: @TonyK: Neither did I, so I am learning now. My main goal is to be able to learn physics with GA, since it has been called a unifying language for physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

$$
\begin{align}
(u\cdot v)^2 - (u\wedge v)^2
& = \frac{1}{4} \left( (uv+vu)^2 - (uv-vu)^2\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{4} \left(uvuv + uvvu + vuuv + vuvu - uvuv + uvvu + vuuv - vuvu \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left( uvvu + vuuv\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left( u^2v^2+u^2v^2\right) \\
& = u^2v^2
\end{align}
$$

The third line to the fourth line is true because

$$uvvu = uv^2u = uuv^2 = u^2v^2$$

where we can re-order terms because $u^2$, $v^2$ are scalars.

Answer (score 1):

In a [paper](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/MultCalc.pdf) i read $$a\cdot b=\dfrac {ab+ba}{2}=b\cdot a$$

and $$a\wedge b=\dfrac {ab-ba}{2}$$
$$(u\cdot v)^2-(u\wedge v)^2$$
$$\left(\dfrac {uv+vu}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac {uv-vu}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\left(\dfrac {uv+vu}{2}-\dfrac {uv-vu}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac {uv+vu}{2}+\dfrac {uv-vu}{2}\right)$$
$$(vu)(uv)$$
$$(uv)^2$$

Comment: I'm not sure it is fully correct but i do this solution on basis of linked paper

Comment: @ionstream007 are $a$ and $b$ vectors? Then what is $ab$, $ba$?

Comment: @Avitus $a$ and $b$ are multivectors, i.e. elements of the Clifford algebra of some vector space. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra

Comment: ab is scaler while a and b are multivectors.I've attached a paper in solution

Comment: I don't understand the last step. Actually you can just start from the R.H.S, $$ (u\cdot v + u\wedge v)(u\cdot v - u \wedge v) = (u\cdot v + u\wedge v)(u\cdot v + v \wedge u) = uvvu $$

Comment: @iostream007 $uv$ is a not a scalar quantity in general. For example consider the geometric algebra $Cl(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $u=u_1e_1+u_2e_2$ and $v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2$. Then $uv = u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + (u_1v_2-u_2v_1)e_1e_2$.

Comment: No offence to anyone.I don't know about multivectors (I know vector calculas that used in physics).In the paper I've read that $a^2=|a|^2\ge 0,$ a is a positive scaler. and it is also written that scaler means real number so is there any difference in uv and vu.

Comment: @iostream007 No offence is taken. It's true that when $a$ is a multivector, $a^2$ is a positive scalar. But multiplying two multivectors $u$ and $v$ does not give a scalar in general. Since $uv=u\cdot v + u\wedge v$, you have $vu = v\cdot u - v\wedge u = u\cdot v - u\wedge v$ so there is no simple relationship between $uv$ and $vu$ in general (unless $u\cdot v=0$ or $u\wedge v=0$).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor so if you can correct my answer,your welcome,cause I've not any more thing to say.And it is also new field for me thanks

Comment: It's not true that $a^2$ is a scalar for an arbitrary multivector; a good example is the Faraday bivector in special relativity.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward, then, using grade projection and associativity of the geometric product.  Consider the product $vuuv$:

$$vuuv = u^2 v^2 = \langle vuuv \rangle_0$$

On the other hand, you can group the products like so

$$vuuv = (vu)(uv) = (v \cdot u) (u \cdot v) + (v \wedge u)(u \wedge v) = (u \cdot v)^2 - (u \wedge v)^2$$

Because you *know* from the first equation that $vuuv$ is a scalar, this is all you need to consider--for instance, there are some bivector terms that I didn't write down, but you can argue that the overall bivector component must be zero, and thus you don't even need to compute them.

Edit: this basic technique of using grade projection and associativity is very useful.  You can, for instance, prove the BAC-CAB rule without using index notation this way (but you do have to approach it with some cyclic products, which is kinda lame).  It's also very useful when you start doing geometric calculus to prove some basic vector calculus identities that would otherwise be cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Although i am not sure i have encountered the BAC-CAB rule yet.

Comment: It's the identity $a \cdot (b \wedge c) = c( a \cdot b) - b (a \cdot c)$.  When written with cross products there's an overall sign change, which is why it's called the BAC-CAB rule.